# Running a gcc execuatble in Iphone simulator or terminal

Tags: iphone, simulator

I have a helloworld.c file, with the contents :

```
#include "stdio.h"
main{ printf"Hello World\n");}
```

I compile it using the arm-apple-darwin-gcc-4.0.1 toolchain and create a hello.out executable.

Can i run this execuatble on iPhone Simulator / terminal ?

Comment: http://eagos.blogsite.org/blog/?p=184

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no.

Kernighan and Ritchie, inventors of the C programming language used to work at AT&T Bell Labs.
"*Hello World*" is a legal trademark of AT&T and is not allowed on their network.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the simulator is still running on Intel. The arm compiler is making an ARM executable. Additionally, you'd need to make a .app bundle for the simulator to recognize the application.